# Angular Unit Test fail: No provider for WebSocketAPI

Tags: angular

I have some of my unit tests failing  in my Angular 10 app because of the following error:

`Failed: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[WebSocketAPI -> WebSocketAPI]: NullInjectorError: No provider for WebSocketAPI!`

Usually this error means that I forgot an import in one of my tests files, but I don't know what to import exactly to fix the error this time. I tried this:

`import { WebSocketAPI } from './service/WebSocketService';`

But it did not work, and Google research does not return anything interesting. I am not very familiar with Angular, does anyone know how to fix this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to put WebSocketAPI as a provider in the beforeEach method of the test file:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [
            AppComponent
        ],
        imports: [
            RouterTestingModule,
            HttpClientTestingModule
        ],
        providers: [
            WebSocketAPI
        ]
    }).compileComponents();
}));
```